# In Judges 8:18 what suggested royalty to Zebah and Zalmunna?

Tags: shoftim--book-of

NOTE: I'm double-posting this question on [*Hermeneutics*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35618/in-judges-818-what-suggested-royalty-to-zebah-and-zalmunna) as it may produce two viewpoints, dunno.

> KJV Judges 8:18 Then said he unto Zebah and Zalmunna, What manner of men were they whom ye slew at Tabor? And they answered, **As thou art, so were they; each one resembled the children of a king**.

Should we write this off as pure fawning and flattery? Or are we intended to understand Jews to be particularly royal?

[image: A child of a king]

I'm wondering if it isn't a reference to [the prohibition against cutting off the corners of the beards](http://bible.oremus.org/?passage=Leviticus%2021:5%E2%80%9321:5&version=nrsv). Would Zebah and Zalumunna have made that association? Or an association with beards in general?

Comment: How did you connect these to each other (Judges to Leviticus)?

Comment: Probably ignorantly. Is there an anachronism?

Comment: Not an anachronism, but that seems like a pretty random connection to make.  It's not the only aspect of a Jew's appearance.  Same with the picture of that Yemenite guy - Yemenites are very good at preserving traditions, but that doesn't mean that they wear the same clothes as Jews wore over 3000 years ago.

Comment: @Heshy I understand that; I'm just trying to make sense of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a statement about Jews in general.  The general picture we get from Judges suggests that Gid'on was almost, but not quite, a king.  This statement shows that even his enemies thought he would make a good king.

The only reason he didn't become a king was because [he refused](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.8.22-23).  [His son did become "king"](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.9.6), but did a terrible job and only ruled for a short time period.